# Focus on many QGraphicsItem in Qt

Tags: qt

To set focus on a [QGraphicsItem](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html) I use the `setFocus()` function.

However what if I need to set focus on two or more [QGraphicsItem](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html) in the same scene at the same time? If this is possible, how would I do this?

Comment: You might be misinterpreting what "focus" means. `setFocus()` "Gives keyboard input focus to this item" -- are you suggesting that you want keyboard input to go to multiple places at the same time?

Comment: @GrishaLevit - why not? I've found that to be useful a number of times. It doesn't make sense for widgets usually, but in the case of graphics items there are uses.

Comment: I think this is an important question. Consider the game Pong with two players using the same keyboard.

Comment: @Ace.C In the case you've mentioned (and any other for that matter) the keyboard input is received by the view (QGraphicsView) and then the logic decides what is to be done (e.g. which player to move).

Comment: @dtech, _I've found that to be useful a number of times._ I will appreciate it if you share some examples when this could be useful.

Answer (score 1):

Not directly, IIRC Qt's view on the subject is that only one object can be in focus at a time.

There is a way around that, however you will have to implement your own focus functionality. You will keep the focus fixed on a static element that will act like an event dispatcher. Then you will manage a list of your focused items, and manually redirect each event the dispatcher receives to the items in the list.

Comment: Could you provide more information about how this would be implemented?